# Can recurrent neural networks be used to classify the language of a word?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

I'm classifying individual words into different languages. I have used neural networks to classify words into languages but I think that they only learn patterns in words at specific locations. For example, a neural network could learn that that the sequence "aille" is characteristic of a french word but it must learn that for different starting point of that sequence within a word. I was thinking that a recurrent network can be used to to learn simply seeing the sequence "aille" at any position in a word is characteristic of the french language.

So can recurrent neural network be used to classify a word to a language?

Comment: Yes of course you could do this.